# Can I use a mix of Classes and functions in one Python program

Tags: python, oop, uml

So I have a Python program where I use classes for certain areas to stop the need for global variables. However, I still use straight up functions in other areas of the program. Would it be good practice to turn all of my code into classes like an OOP or is a mix ok. I'm also wondering what UML diagrams work well for a mix because I'm not sure if a class or sequence diagram will work.

Answer (score 1):

Usually that's something for the team to decide, generally it's considered a good practice not to mix functions and classes in a single module. Most UML diagram tools for Python work fine with plain functions. A class in this case is your module and it has only one instance.

Comment: So i can use a module Main as a section on a UML class diagram and connect it to classes.

Comment: Yes. I prefer not to write UML manually though, but rather to generate it from code, You can use pyreverse https://www.logilab.org/blogentry/6883, it is the part of pylint package, so you may already  have it installed.

Comment: I have got it showing a class diagram but it only shows the classes and not the modules is there a command to change this, Thanks